# How can an oblique asymptote be $y = x$ , as $x\to \infty$?

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

In my Calculus book, an oblique asymptote defined as:

> ***Oblique Asymptote***:
>
> the function $y = f(x)$ **has** an oblique asymptote $y = mx + n$, if:
>
> 1. $$\lim_{x\to \infty} {f(x) \over x} = m$$ where **$m$** is a **finite number**.
> 2. $$\lim_{x\to \infty} [{f(x) - mx}] = n$$
>    where $n$ is a **finite number** as well.

My problem:

In the exercises book, there's an exercise:

> $$f(x) =  x + {\sin(x) \over x} $$

I found there's no vertical asymptote, as in the solutions.

But, I also found that there's no oblique asymptote,
but the solutions tell the opposite.

My solution:

> $$m = \lim_{x \to \infty} x + {\sin x \over x} = \lim_{x \to \infty} x + {0} = \lim_{x \to \infty} {x} = {\infty}. $$

As we can see, by his own definition, the asymptote couldn't be - because $m$ is infinity,

as the definition defines that $m$ and $n$ must be finite.

So how the oblique asymptote is $y = x$?

Thank you!

Comment: It's $m = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac {f(x)}x$, not $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)$.

Comment: @Kaster You're right, I'll fix it, but still - I can't understand how an horzintal asymptote can be infinity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have
$$m=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}1+\frac{\sin x}{x^2}=1$$
and
$$n=\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)-x=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}=0$$
so 
$$y=x$$
is the oblique asymptote of the function at $\infty$

Comment: Oh ... >< . So only m and n must be finit but not x. you're right, I didn't noticed that. thanks! (I'll accept your answer in few minutes)

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: I like your extensive gravatar wardrobe!

Answer (score 2):

$m=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}1+\frac{\sin x}{x^2}=1$. Now you can continue.